# База данных для доски объявлений

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Я хотел-бы посоветоваться. Есть сайт - доска объявлений, на котором  я проектирую базу данных. В каждом товаре есть основные данные это - категория, подкатегория, описание, цена и дополнительные данные (в виде ключ-значения) относящиеся к каждой подкатегории. Например к подкатегории **Недвижимость - Тип: купля, продажа; лифт: есть, нету** и т.д; к подкатегории **Автомобили - Марка: BMW, Renault; Цвет: красный, синий** и т.д. И количество дополнительных данных (тоесть ключ-значение), для каждой категории может быть разным, а может вообще и не быть (тоесть для данного товара будет указываться только **Основные данные**).

Эти данные нужны будут для поиска товара и при просмотре товара.

Какие таблицы и столбцы для этого мне надо сделать, чтобы он работал быстро.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону EAV.